# How do I convert an array of strings to a list of numbers?

Tags: python, list

I want to convert all strings which contain words in an array to ints.

The list is:

```
['Met', 'Mod', 'Goa', 'Con', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Bac',
 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Goa', 'Mod', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Goa', 'Mod',
 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Bac']
```

I want to assign `Met` to `1`, `Mod` to `2`, `Goal` to `3`, `Con` to `4`, and `Bac` to `5`.

How do I make the list into this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5', '5', '2', '2', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
 '3', '2', '5', '5', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '5']
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a dictionary.

```
d = {'Met':1, 'Mod':2, 'Goa':3, 'Con':4, 'Bac':5}
l = ['Met', 'Mod', 'Goa', 'Con', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Mod',
     'Mod', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Goa', 'Mod',
     'Bac', 'Bac', 'Goa', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Bac']
new_list = list(map(d.get, l))
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
```

Note that I've assigned each keyword to a *number* as you requested rather than to a *string representing a number* as you demonstrated.

Comment: @cdlane - I think your interpretation of the problem is absolutely 100% wrong. The OP said "I want to assign Met to 1, Mod to 2, Goal to 3, Con to 4, and Bac to 5," not "I want to assign each word to the 1-indexed location of its first appearance in the original list."

Comment: I think the fact that the first five elements happen to be unique and in the order described leaves this open to interpretation, given the title and first sentence of the problem.  I guess we'll have to wait for the OP to weigh in.

Comment: How about the fact that they specifically stated each desired value for each word, rather than saying that the location of the first occurrence of each word determines its value? There is no indication that your algorithm is even close to reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = {'Met':1, 'Mod':2, 'Goa':3, 'Con':4, 'Bac':5}
lst = ['Met', 'Mod', 'Goa', 'Con', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Bac','Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Goa', 'Mod', 'Bac', 'Bac', 'Goa', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Mod', 'Bac']
new = []
for each in lst:
    new.append(l[each])
print new
```